# Django, Gunicorn: Cannot import name views

Tags: python, django, bash, nginx, gunicorn

I'm attempting to set up a Django project with Nginx and Gunicorn. I think I am encountering some issues with paths that I can't seem to figure out.

my root virtualenv dir: `/var/www/webapps/testapp/`

If I run `gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001` from  `/var/www/webapps/testapp/testapp/` (apologies for the naming conventions...) It works!

However... If I attempt to run from the bash script I am using to start gunicorn the project seems to run but when I attempt to load a page I get these errors:

```
ImportError at /home/
cannot import name views
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://URL/home/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name views
Exception Location: /var/www/webapps/testapp/testapp/testapp/urls.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /var/www/webapps/testapp/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/var/www/webapps/testapp/testapp',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/bin',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/testapp',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/bin',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python27.zip',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python2.7',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/var/www/webapps/testapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 21 May 2014 15:26:45 +0000
```

The bash script I am using is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="testapp2"                                       # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/var/www/webapps/testapp/testapp          # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/var/www/webapps/testapp/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=testappuser                                     # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=16                                       # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings              # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=mysite.wsgi                      # WSGI module name
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/webapps/testapp/bin`

echo "Starting $NAME as "whoami"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH`

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Using the bash script does not work and I can't seem to figure out why. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is `/var/www/webapps/testapp/testapp/testapp` the actual location?

Comment: Yes config files such as models.py     tests.py      urls.py etc.. are located here.

Comment: Have you tried changing `DJANGODIR` to the same directory you're in when you run `gunicorn` manually?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue lay with directory permissions and the user running the gunicorn process.

All sorted now, thanks!